# tracert is showing only source and destination

Tags: web-server

On my windows system tracert to my website output is showing only source and destination. The output is

1.192.168.1.1 : My modem
2.Myserver

tracert complete

Can anybody explain.

Thanks!

shams

Answer (score 2):

Erm... there's no intermediate hops from you to your website.  You are either on the same switch/hub as the web server, or you're VPN'd to the same network as the web server (and even then there would potentially be an intermediate hop or two).

Tracert shows the number of hops between you and a target.  If I tracert from my PC in Canada to a server in Australia, there are a lot of intermediate routers between us that will show up.

If I tracert from my PC in Canada... to the printer on my desk in Canada... there's either 1 or no hops (depending on my network complexity).

Comment: You are correct in that case. But my PC is at china and server is at UK.

Comment: So you're either a) VPN'd to the network in the UK or b) SSH/Telnet/RDP'd to a machine on the UK network and are executing the command from there

Comment: None of them. Does tracert have any option to enable/disable showing intermediate hops?